# Size of files compressed with python gzip module is not reduced

Tags: python, gzip

I made a simple test code that generates a lot of integers and writes them into a compressed file using the [gzip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html) module.

```
import gzip
for idx in range(100000):
    with gzip.open('output.gz', 'ab') as f:
        line = (str(idx) + '\n').encode()
        f.write(line)
```

The compressed file is created but when I decompress it, the raw data are actually a lot smaller:

```
$ ls -l
  588890 output
 3288710 output.gz
```

Can you please explain what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You're appending 100000 separate times to the gzip instead of zipping 100000 items. Swap the order of the with-statement and for-loop, which results in file size of 212863.

Comment: @IljaEverilä How does that differ? I expected that every time I append into the compressed file, it decompresses, the data are appended and the result is compressed back again.

Comment: It's more akin to concatenating 100000 separate gzip files together. Their headers etc. will start to count. Take your favourite hex-editor and have a look at the file's contents. You should be seeing a ton of "output" strings etc.

Comment: @IljaEverilä As a funny sidenote: The compressed result is about 200 kB but when I compress the raw data manually using 7z or tar.xz method, the size reduces to about 17 kB. I should look for some better module than gzip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assumption that append mode would append to the existing stream is wrong. Instead it concatenates a new stream to the existing gzip file. When decompressing these are then concatenated transparently as if you had compressed a single file. But each stream contains its own [header and footer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip#File_format) and those add up. Inspecting your file reveals

```
 % hexdump -C output.gz|head -n5
00000000  1f 8b 08 08 2e e7 03 5b  02 ff 6f 75 74 70 75 74  |.......[..output|
00000010  00 33 e0 02 00 12 cd 4a  7e 02 00 00 00 1f 8b 08  |.3.....J~.......|
00000020  08 2e e7 03 5b 02 ff 6f  75 74 70 75 74 00 33 e4  |....[..output.3.|
00000030  02 00 53 fc 51 67 02 00  00 00 1f 8b 08 08 2e e7  |..S.Qg..........|
00000040  03 5b 02 ff 6f 75 74 70  75 74 00 33 e2 02 00 90  |.[..output.3....|
```

Note the repetition of the magic number `1f 8b`, which marks the beginning of a new stream.

In general it's usually a bad idea to repeatedly open a file in append mode in a loop. Instead open the file once for writing and write the contents in a loop:

```
with gzip.open('output.gz', 'wb') as f:
    for idx in range(100000):
        line = (str(idx) + '\n').encode()
        f.write(line)
```

The resulting file is around 200 kiB, compared to the original 3 MiB.

Comment: I had no idea that your and my code (a simple interchange of `with` and `for` statements) can result in a different output. Very interesting. Thank you for this deep explanation of what's actually happening behind the code.